# How to run multiple javascript(nodejs) files in powershell at once?

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, powershell, cmd

If I wanted to run 10 files (.js files) on my desktop, which are all located in the same folder, how would I run every script at once?

Currently I am running them all one by one by typing "node script.js" in powershell for each and every one.

Comment: The answers here, including the selected answer, do not run multiple files "at once." These answers run them sequentially. If they need to run concurrently, see PowerShell `Invoke-Command` or the cmd.exe `START` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 common ways of running multiple commands in a single one.

First is doing them all in a single line using `&&`:

```
node 1.js && node 2.js && node 3.js && ...
```

You could use a loop if your files are named numerically, otherwise just add all those names there.

Using `&&` means the right command will only run if the left command runs successfully, so if any of your files raises an exception, the other files wouldn't run.

Another option is by using a `.bat`/`.ps1` file. `.bat` are used for CMD, `.ps1` are used for PowerShell.

You can however run `.bat` files from a PowerShell window, so you could save a `run.bat` file like this:

```
node 1.js
node 2.js
node 3.js
...
```

And just run it by typing `.\<file>.bat` on the same folder.

EDIT: @John Schmitz answer is probably better for a more general 'run everything on this folder' solution. You could even add it to a `.ps1` file and run it as `.\run.ps1`, but I'm pretty sure there's some needed configuration to run `.ps1` files like this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    Get-ChildItem -Filter *.js | ForEach {
         node $_.Fullname 
    }
```